# How can I fix the problem with Gmail? Gmail marked email with passed SPF, DKIM and DMARC as spam

Tags: email, gmail, spf, dkim, dmarc

Gmail moves messages to spam folder. PTR records for ipv4 and ipv6 are available. I have the headers:
SPF:    PASS с IP-адресом 2a05:480:0:992f:0:0:0:2.
DKIM:   'PASS', domain drom.com.ua
DMARC:  'PASS'

```
Delivered-To: vostoknefteproduct@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a9d:522:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id 31csp351612otw;
        Fri, 5 Apr 2019 05:26:18 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: APXvYqzWa1UxYEepV1tor3akYHi1DLXojOZnr61fkANdKlbOkDM880aGrAB9RzQdjipusdfEcAVt
X-Received: by 2002:a2e:87d2:: with SMTP id v18mr7262855ljj.4.1554467178382;
        Fri, 05 Apr 2019 05:26:18 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1554467178; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=TTDI9m3Rt73dRkcImzRRAM5n98TJgwNxCnrbvKNVMAIOdrWk/iG+NU2OrR3/vDr7Gp
         fQmPmqt5QyEdZpO1G+He8uYckwETdCQFhVACDVcC5FJ8GWnWsys5p9vbFYzlYh89OZR+
         gFfJkt+lb5z607n03Sr9zMW9HiJVBGKLr+SFCsG8u/AOmZCF9wZtGwaP69E+7b916njn
         WZ+Pz9Q/+DyDKaCOQWrdUlTS5GvrfK/c86/5lA0AjoZN90/Rj+uGlbIROqKUXoLbA/z3
         G9LM9df3a6/kfAZBkzHB3PqCaiUhEKbSrcpLj1gT1fKHZKWOnkqb9hlcYwMX2OcHbpA8
         zTtg==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=content-language:thread-index:mime-version:message-id:date:subject
         :to:from:dkim-signature;
        bh=qI0pd1OCLQLqqFvztD8zxwZ0XJBtraToDzc2t4i88s0=;
        b=uLJIPEtdroC8P6tqoyfOikNhNzEmtmNRGpgoOefyyN/0wdAqExsSoUxZ9UKLL31lST
         AT7J8/ZOEMuGa/wn1dSUHfwRqiZl7d/rxM+AtT2a1PaSSLulOgz9HQDGw1r81QXKnZMI
         XzsGpuPmz9e3apEtczYBM0E3zYjm5Z2ITmpnrk9MluAnEuqE370R/24ixS1W2+EEG4mY
         FXZ6AsImGfZGFr75zc9kLTPgBxa1hxghD0mu6RIACf45b5ljQZQuspj8kRyhw5NX30SA
         FRwg1TwRjm3N+kmaUiDv4M64Y7s1d/PU7Gr4rb33v8Ia/aEOpeFfKLs2NfKmiiuvqBh7
         94vg==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@drom.com.ua header.s=dkim header.b=G8nYIwzB;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of shop@drom.com.ua designates 2a05:480:0:992f::2 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=shop@drom.com.ua;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=drom.com.ua
Return-Path: <shop@drom.com.ua>
Received: from drom.com.ua (drom.com.ua. [2a05:480:0:992f::2])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id z24si17168655ljj.124.2019.04.05.05.26.18
        for <vostoknefteproduct@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Fri, 05 Apr 2019 05:26:18 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of shop@drom.com.ua designates 2a05:480:0:992f::2 as permitted sender) client-ip=2a05:480:0:992f::2;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@drom.com.ua header.s=dkim header.b=G8nYIwzB;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of shop@drom.com.ua designates 2a05:480:0:992f::2 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=shop@drom.com.ua;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=drom.com.ua
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=drom.com.ua ; s=dkim; h=Content-Type:MIME-Version:Message-ID:Date:Subject:To:From:Sender: Reply-To:Cc:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-ID:Content-Description: Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender:Resent-To:Resent-Cc:Resent-Message-ID: In-Reply-To:References:List-Id:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:List-Subscribe: List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive; bh=qI0pd1OCLQLqqFvztD8zxwZ0XJBtraToDzc2t4i88s0=; b=G8nYIwzBB+jpn8qK83ZCo7vu+m AM/RFrxq/PP8dITX1PNXqINAjHPSu2rBVsdE5QTMPDoaHYPbOeC9wFHFMfYspdy/JyQAh4A8hmSNz HgtnwRBVR14Nht8DAqeql7CCrOom0KNS0SQ95dTnOy42/5bFommziwUghHGgzyzjUav4=;
Received: from [176.98.31.190] (helo=DESKTOPV2831BB) by drom.com.ua with esmtpsa (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256) (Exim 4.91) (envelope-from <shop@drom.com.ua>) id 1hCNvF-0000Rn-J9 for vostoknefteproduct@gmail.com; Fri, 05 Apr 2019 15:26:17 +0300
From: "DROM - служба обработки заказов" <shop@drom.com.ua>
To: <vostoknefteproduct@gmail.com>
Subject: Test title
Date: Fri, 5 Apr 2019 15:26:17 +0300
Message-ID: <005901d4ebaa$c4b3ea80$4e1bbf80$@drom.com.ua>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_NextPart_000_005A_01D4EBC3.EA0197B0"
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 16.0
Thread-Index: AdTrqr/vXGG/i/4HRdu0LENUGEwBuw==
Content-Language: ru
X-Scanned-By: ClamAV 0.101.1; Fri, 05 Apr 2019 15:26:17 +0300
```

Where can be the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this seems to be business as usual with gmail. Their spam filter seems entirely arbitrary and uncontrollable by recipients - for example adding addresses to your address book, marking messages as "not spam", or repeatedly moving messages from spam to your inbox does not help, and nor does following their guidelines, which include implementing measures such as SPF, DKIM and DMARC, just as you've done. On my own gmail account, I often find messages sent to myself end up in spam!

Their [postmaster tools](https://postmaster.google.com/) are also broken - this is supposed to provide a feedback mechanism that allows server admins to see why IPs or domains are being blocked or spam filtered, however, it doesn't work properly, and it's very common to see domains & IPs marked as "bad" despite having zero spam reports. There is also no support available for postmaster tools, so you can't even report such problems. It might be worth trying anyway just see what they think of you.

In short, you are entirely at google's mercy - even if you're doing everything that they ask, your messages may still get spam filtered, and you have no recourse.

Comment: Thank you. Now I hate Google policy

Comment: It could be that I have particularly bad experiences with it, and I may be being overly pessimistic – your mileage may vary! I steer clear of anything involving google or facebook where possible; they're awful companies.

Comment: Still relevant today, GMail simply marks emails from my mail server as spam if they are sent through IPv6, as in the original post SPF, DKIM, DMARC, PTR etc are all correct.. Unfortunately it looks like that IPv6 can't be used by a mail server unless you are google..